# Reference a Named Range Cell (Validation List) in the same Workbook to change the Account Number Filter in a Excel Sage Sequel Database Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, sage

I am trying to dynamically change the Filter in an Excel Sage Power Query from a Named Range single cell D3 in below Image. D3 is a selection List from a Chart of Accounts in same Workbook.

[Stackoverflow query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xGDl.png)

Per the image above, the dynamic MonthNo works a charm for selecting the period/s, and I have used the same /similar code for the dynamic Account Number, but whilst it reads the AccountNo (Named Range) it gives the correct result, however the Table comes up empty as below Image.

[Table Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJIQ7.png)

My code is as follows:-

```
let
MonthNo= Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MonthNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),
AccountNo= Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AccountNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),    
Source = Sql.Database("VM65\SAGE200", "UK_GamaAviationLtd", [Query="SELECT #(lf)NLNominalAccount.AccountNumber, NLNominalAccount.AccountCostCentre, NLNominalAccount.AccountDepartment, NLNominalAccount.AccountName,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.TransactionDate, NLPostedNominalTran.PostedDate, NLPostedNominalTran.GoodsValueInBaseCurrency, NLPostedNominalTran.Reference,#(lf)NLPostedNominalTran.Narrative, NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber, NLPostedNominalTran.UserName, NLPostedNominalTran.UserNumber,#(lf)SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber#(lf)FROM NLPostedNominalTran, NLNominalAccount, SYSAccountingPeriod, SYSFinancialYear#(lf)WHERE NLPostedNominalTran.NLNominalAccountID = NLNominalAccount.NLNominalAccountID#(lf)AND NLPostedNominalTran.SYSAccountingPeriodID = SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSAccountingPeriodID#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.SYSFinancialYearID = SYSFinancialYear.SYSFinancialYearID#(lf)AND SYSAccountingPeriod.PeriodNumber <="&MonthNo&"#(lf)ORDER BY NLPostedNominalTran.UniqueReferenceNumber DESC"]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TransactionDate", type date}, {"GoodsValueInBaseCurrency", Currency.Type}, {"PostedDate", type date}}),
Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date Time Refresh", each DateTime.LocalNow() as datetime),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom1,{{"Date Time Refresh", type datetime}}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"AccountNumber", "Account Number"}, {"AccountCostCentre", "Cost Centre"}, {"AccountDepartment", "Department"}, {"AccountName", "Account Name"}, {"TransactionDate", "Trans Date"}, {"PostedDate", "Posted Date"}, {"GoodsValueInBaseCurrency", "Posted Value"}, {"Reference", "Journal Ref"}, {"Narrative", "Journal Narrative"}, {"UniqueReferenceNumber", "URN"}, {"UserName", "User Name"}, {"UserNumber", "User Number"}, {"PeriodNumber", "Posted Period"}}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Posted Value", Currency.Type}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Trans Date", "Trans Date - Copy"),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"Account Number", "Cost Centre", "Department", "Account Name", "Trans Date", "Posted Date", "Posted Value", "Journal Ref", "Journal Narrative", "URN", "User Name", "User Number", "Trans Date - Copy", "Posted Period", "Date Time Refresh"}),
#"Extracted Year" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Trans Date - Copy", Date.Year, Int64.Type}}),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Extracted Year",{{"Trans Date - Copy", "Year"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Full Account No", each [Account Number]&[Cost Centre]&[Department]),
#"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Full Account No", "Account Number", "Cost Centre", "Department", "Account Name", "Trans Date", "Posted Date", "Posted Value", "Journal Ref", "Journal Narrative", "URN", "User Name", "User Number", "Year", "Posted Period", "Date Time Refresh"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns1", each ([Full Account No] = "&AccountNo&")),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Year", Order.Ascending}, {"Posted Period", Order.Ascending}, {"Trans Date", Order.Ascending}})
in
#"Sorted Rows"
```

I have tried the above code where I have inserted the 2nd line `AccountNo= Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AccountNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),`, with the result of the empty table per the image, so it is not filtering dynamically. This code refers to the Named single cell Range in D3 (AccountNo) in the Workbook. I have tried various alternate iterations with no success. I have also tried changing the `AccountNo= Text.From` to `AccountNo= Number.From` which comes up with an Error, whilst with `AccountNo= Text.From` when viewing AccountNo step I can see the result of the Account Number.

I have also changed the second last line of code from `#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns1", each ([Full Account No] = "B20458")),` to `#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns1", each ([Full Account No] = "&AccountNo&")),`. When I insert `"B20458"` in place of `"&AccountNo&"`, I get results and table for Account Number B20458, however I am wanting to change the Account Number dynamically from the Drop-down List in cell D3.

I also wish the added complication that if No Account Number is selected in D3 (Blank) then NO Filter is applied if possible.

Many thanks for your trouble.

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere", each Text.From([Account Number]) = Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="AccountNo"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]))
```

[image]

Comment: Goodness gracious me, what an idjut I am, thank you horseyride, I moved the step down from higher up and should have changed it. I guess I notice, that it should be whatever the preceding step the whole way down?

Comment: Apologies @horseyride I have posted the not correct code above. My actual code does have the #"Reordered Columns1" before it. Should I repost my question correctly and delete this one, or edit the above? The code I have has I thought like the MonthNo in the above with the attempted Bold ** in the 2nd line of code was pulling the text from my Named Range in cell D3? which I have referenced in the     #"Filtered Rows" line.

Comment: Thank you horseyride, I have updated the actual code and explanations better, explaining what code I have inserted in 2nd line pulling the Account Number from the Single Cell Named Range, which when I click on AccountNo it gives me the Account Number in D3. I have also changed the 2nd last line to put in "&AccountNo&" in place of  "B20458", similar to what you helped me with the dynamic MonthNo that works.

Comment: Hi horseyride, thank you, your solution worked a treat, much appreciated, first class.

I will post a new query to enquire if there is anyway of using an IF statement in Power Query that if one leaves the Account Number blank which returns a zero contents table, that it will unfilter the Account Number altogether instead of blank table. Thank you.